# Python: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, python-multithreading, urlopen

I having a multi threaded python program, It will continuously open connection with a local URL(**http://testing.com/sendMessages_mock.php**), I have installed the WAMP and having sendMessages_mock.php file in local for testing purpose. Sometimes, I get **"[Errno 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it"**

Each thread will call this function. For every one second, there will hundreds of thread calling this function. Getting this exception only for few thread calls. Any thoughts on this ?

```
def sendMessage(body):
    try:
        request = Request(url="http://testing.com/sendMessages_mock.php", data=json.dumps(body))
        request.add_header('Authorization', 'key=' + CONST.API_KEY)
        request.add_header('Content-Type', 'application/json')
        response = urlopen(request)
        responseData = response.read().decode('utf-8')

    except Exception as exceptionErr:
        print("Oops! " + str(traceback.format_exc()))
```

Comment: The server side listens for connections but the `listen` call has a backlog - a maximum number of incoming connection requests that haven't been accepted yet. When that request queue is too large, the server TCP stack may start rejecting the connections. That's probably what you are seeing. You likely can configure the server for a bigger backlog, but also consider that this is normal back-pressure telling your clients to chill a bit.

Answer (score 1):

If too many calls per second are a problem that causes WAMP to refuse requests and you'd like to solve this on Python side, you could write limiter class which would handle sendMessage execution and limit number of calls.

Mind you this is my first answer to someone else's question, so it might be absolutely wrong. Please have reasonable amount of scepticism.

```
#python 2.7
import threading

class Throttle(object):
    def __init__(self, call_limit, interval):
        self.call_limit = call_limit
        self.interval = interval
        self.cleaner = None
        self.buffer = threading.Semaphore(call_limit)
        self.calls_in_buffer = 0

    def call(self, function, *args):
        self.buffer.acquire()

        self.calls_in_buffer += 1
        try:
            return function(*args)
        except:
            raise
        finally:
            if self.cleaner == None:
                self._init_cleaner()

    def _drain(self):
        for i in range(self.call_limit):
            self.calls_in_buffer -= 1
            self.buffer.release()
        self.cleaner = None

    def _init_cleaner(self):
        self.cleaner = threading.Timer(self.interval, self._drain)
        self.cleaner.daemon = True
        self.cleaner.start()
```

Making calls through such class would effectively throttle requests, so server will be able to handle them.

Comment: Assuming this works, it would possibly be even nicer as a [decorator](http://python-3-patterns-idioms-test.readthedocs.io/en/latest/PythonDecorators.html#function-decorators). In this case it would accept the function to wrap in its constructor, and `call` would be replaced with `__call__`.